# Twitter like follow suggestions stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, stored-procedures

I have two tables:

**Users**

```
id, firstName, lastName, location (geography), facebookId
```

**Followers**

```
userId, followerId, followDatetime
```

and I want to create a stored procedure to present to a user follow suggestions (users to follow), but in an efficient way. The stored procedure should return the following users:

1. All users which have a Facebook ID that can be found in a comma separated list of FB IDs (this list will be provided to the SP as a parameter) - **Priority 1**
2. Select "the friends of my friends" (the users that my friends follow) - **Priority 2**
3. Users based on location, with a distance of x kilometers - **Priority 3**
4. All users with similar first name or last name as my friends (my friends are the people I follow) - **Priority 4**
5. All other users that I don't follow yet, randomly selected - **Priority 5**

I want the result to contain only users that I don't follow yet, to be paginated and ordered by Priority, without duplicate rows.

The columns I want to retrieve for each user are the following:

```
id, firstName, lastName, number of followers
```

What would be an efficient way to achieve this?

Comment: Is this a homework assignment? #2 can be done by select distinct fOfF.followerId from Followers as friends join Followers as fOfF on friends.followerId = fOfF.userid where friends.userId = @me

Comment: Well, actually it's for a personal project. I thought about having a separate select for each requirement, then to use UNION, order by priority and insert all this data into a temporary table so I can paginate. After pagination, for each row I have to select the number of followers. I think I can make this work, but will be efficient?

Comment: I don't think this is going to perform great. If you do implement it all in SQL and return all the results in a pagable fashion instead of limiting the results (say to 100 suggestions) then I would store the results e.g. Suggestions(userID, suggestionRank int, suggestedUserId). Then you can just return results from that table for subsequent page requests. In a big system (like the real twitter) computing the suggestions would be an async or background process rather than on demand. That way when the user goes to add friends getting the suggestions is immediate. (And #4 seems a strange feature)